# Conditional display with XSLT..?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

below is my XML code -

```
<topic no=1>
<desc>......</desc>
<references>
    <book>XSLT Essentials</book>
    <chapter>11</chapter>
    <book>XSLT Cookbook</book>
    <chapter>10</chapter>
</references>
</topic>    

<topic no=2>
<desc>......</desc>
<references>
    <book>Javascript in 10 mins</book>
    <chapter>11</chapter>
</references>
</topic>

<topic no=3>
<desc>......</desc>
<references>
    <book></book>
    <chapter></chapter>
</references>
</topic>
```

First I am explaining the situation.

The HTML output with respect to references tag only, I am looking for is like -

for topic no=1

```
<table><tr>
  <td>Book</td><td>Chapter</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td>XSLT Essentials</td><td>11</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td>XSLT Cookbook</td><td>10</td></tr>
</table>
```

......

for topic no=2

```
<table><tr>
  <td>Book</td><td>Chapter</td></tr>
<tr>
  <td>Javascript in 10 mins</td><td>11</td></tr>
</table>
```

......

for topic no=3
**No table as No references used.**

This is a sample, so the XML file contains only 2 references in the first case, but these references might even go to 12 in some cases and 0 (zero) in some cases.

Have a nice day - John :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is probably one of the simplest and shortest solutions. Do note that no explicit conditional instructions are used at all**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="topic/*|text()"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*[topic]">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="topic/references[book/text()]">
    <table>
     <tr><td>Book</td><td>Chapter</td></tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
    </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="book">
  <tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
   <td><xsl:value-of select=
       "following-sibling::chapter[1]"/>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided input text** (corrected to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <topic no="1">
        <desc>......</desc>
        <references>
            <book>XSLT Essentials</book>
            <chapter>11</chapter>
            <book>XSLT Cookbook</book>
            <chapter>10</chapter>
        </references>
    </topic>
    <topic no="2">
        <desc>......</desc>
        <references>
            <book>Javascript in 10 mins</book>
            <chapter>11</chapter>
        </references>
    </topic>
    <topic no="3">
        <desc>......</desc>
        <references>
            <book></book>
            <chapter></chapter>
        </references>
    </topic>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Book</td>
      <td>Chapter</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>XSLT Essentials</td>
      <td>11</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>XSLT Cookbook</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Book</td>
      <td>Chapter</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Javascript in 10 mins</td>
      <td>11</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation**: Appropriate use of templates pattern matching.

**The Rule of Dimitre**: Whenever you have an explicit conditional instruction (`<xsl:if>`, `<xsl:choose>`, `<xsl:when>`, etc), this probably means that you haven't used template pattern matching as you should.

**To learn more why it is good to completely avoid conditional instructions:**
Read this essential Pluralsight course:

[**Tactical Design Patterns in .NET: Control Flow**](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/tactical-design-patterns-dot-net-control-flow/table-of-contents)

by **[Zoran Horvat](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/authors/zoran-horvat)**

Comment: Thanks a lot... :). Rather, I was waiting for your reply. So kind of you.. :) and the way you answer with explanation is the best way to learn (& teach too ;)). Was it you, who developed this, I mean XSLT..? Thanks a lot again.. :)

Comment: @John: You are welcome. Yes, XSLT is a fasinating, elegant, powerful functional language. I wasn't among the creators of XSLT 1.0/2.0 but XSLT has been my hobby and occasionally used in my professional tasks, for the last 11 years.

Comment: @Dimitre, well done! I know that XQuery isn't asked for here, but you referred to short solutions, and this XQuery one is kind of short: `//book[text()]/..!element table{<tr><td>Book</td><td>Chapter</td></tr>,book!<tr><td>{text()}</td><td>{following::*[1]/text()}</td></tr>}`

Comment: @Gunther, Yes, Xpath 3.0 in general and the simple-mapping operator `!` give us extreme expressive power and elegance.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<xsl:template match="content">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="references" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="references">
          <xsl:if test="book != '']">
           <table>
           <tr><td>Book</td><td>Chapter</td></tr>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="book" />
         </table>
          </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="book">
    <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td><td><xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::chapter[1]" /></td></tr>
</xsl:template>
```

tested and it works ;)

Comment: I used `//following-sibling::*` instead of what you gave... Now working as per my need... Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: @kim- Its working but only when there are references used. If I don't have references then drawing table... please read my question again and see what I have written in bold.. :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this, it looks like you first need to pass a parameter to your XSLT to indicate which topic you want. How this is done very much depends on what processor you are using, but within your XSLT you will need the following line:

```
<xsl:param name="topic" select="'1'"/>
```

(1 is the default parameter here)

Then, to get all the relevant topics for the parameter, it is simply a case of doing the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//topic[@no=$topic][references/book != '']"/>
```

This will also ignore topics with no references present.

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:param name="topic" select="'1'"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:if test="//topic[@no=$topic][references/book != '']">
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>Book</td>
               <td>Chapter</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//topic[@no=$topic][references/book != '']"/>
         </table>
      </xsl:if>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="topic">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="references"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="references">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="book"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="book">
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::chapter[1]"/>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following input XML

```
<topics>
   <topic no="1">
      <desc>......</desc>
      <references>
         <book>XSLT Essentials</book>
         <chapter>11</chapter>
         <book>XSLT Cookbook</book>
         <chapter>10</chapter>
      </references>
   </topic>
   <topic no="2">
      <desc>......</desc>
      <references>
         <book>Javascript in 10 mins</book>
         <chapter>11</chapter>
      </references>
   </topic>
   <topic no="3">
      <desc>......</desc>
      <references>
         <book/>
         <chapter/>
      </references>
   </topic>
</topics>
```

The following is output

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Book</td>
      <td>Chapter</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>XSLT Essentials</td>
      <td>11</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>XSLT Cookbook</td>
      <td>10</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When the parameter is changed to 2, the following is output:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Book</td>
      <td>Chapter</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Javascript in 10 mins</td>
      <td>11</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When the parameter is changed to 3, nothing is output.

Comment: Tim- Thanks a lot. I think it would easy and efficient style to add attribute with value as Y or N to `<references>` tag instead of `<topic>` tag.